Making a basic n panel template with working properties
I'm trying to display some different property types on a n-panel. I would like to level up from using operator buttons, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a panel with some properties.
import bpy

class MyProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    bpy.types.Scene.my_int = bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="int",
        description="integer",
        default=1,
        min=0,
        max=1024,
        step=1)
   
    bpy.types.Scene.my_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="float",
        description="float",
        default=1.0,
        min=0.0625,
        max=1024.0,
        step=0.25,
        precision=2)
    
    bpy.types.Scene.my_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="enum",
        description="enumerator",
        items=[
            ("1", "first_option", "description")
            ("2", "second_option", "description")
            ("3", "third_option", "description")
               ]
        default="1")

    bpy.types.Scene.my_string = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="string",
        description="words and stuff",
        default="type here..")

    bpy.types.Scene.my_collection = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(
        name = "collection",
        description= "idk wht this does yet"
    )



class TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_test_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Test'

    def draw(self, context):
            layout = self.layout
            scene = context.scene
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(scene, "my_int")
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(scene, "my_float")
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(scene, "my_enum")
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(scene, "my_string")
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(scene, "my_collection")

## note: my non-proprety classes (panels, operators) are loaded by __init__.py

## register properties!
def register():
    pass # ??

def unregister():
    pass

I'm already using an autoloader to load panels and operators somewhere else, so I want to know how to load register the property group correctly and what the syntax looks like. I haven't been able to find any examples of this anywhere.

I fon't know python, but isn't there an example in the list if you go to Blender's Scripting layout tab then look at the list under Templates > Python in the Text Editor?

none of the templates show this.

Ok. Worth a try!

tldr:  replace = with :, also, don't use bpy.types.Scene  in the property group annotations. in register you should register the property group then bpy.types.Scene.my_property_group = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProps)

@JohnEason Interestingly there really is no template for a simple N-panel lol. I would have expected this to be part of the templates. IMHO UI Simple Panel template should have given such a template for the N-Panel since that is the most common panel for addons.

@HarryMcKenzie Maybe time for someone who uses python to suggest that Blender add it to the templates! :^)
